# EF6 - BUG? - Migration checks project's DB, but write to build's DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

***Meanwhile I've found at least the cause for my issue. If you don't want to read through all steps I've done, just scroll down to Edit1 at the end of this post.***

I'm currently facing an issue with EF 6 where I don't know if it's a bug, by design or me not understanding EF enough :(

I have **3 projects** in one solution: a server project, a client project and a model project.
The model contains the entities used by my server's and client's context classes, each of them within the namespace of my server's and client's project.

My context classes (both inside the model namespace) contained **2 DBSet** objects: **[Srv|Cli]Entity** and **CoreEntity**. Both are abstract classes my "real" entities are inheriting from, so I don't have to define each entity inside my context class.
The result is a new table for each entity inheriting from each of these base classes and a table for each of these base classes themselves called **CoreEntityRegistry** and **[Srv|Cli]EntityRegistry**.

The first thing I did was enabling migration, adding initial migration and updating database without any issues.

Than I've worked on the ***client*** code and data modelling and afterwards enabled migration and added initial migration. At this point I cannot remember anymore if I did a database update or not, but I suppose so, because if not I would have received some exceptions trying to access database elements not available for usage during debugging.

Back to the model project I edited some entities for the server and I think for the server and client (= Core), too.

Than I ran `Add-Migration` for ***server*** project again, but this time EF complained about a pending migration. Actually this was impossible, but I thought I just run `Update-Database` again to be sure.
This command was running successfully.
But as soon as I tried to `Add-Migration` again: same pending error from EF.

Looking at the database table ***__MigrationHistory***, I could see my migration, but the ***ContextKey*** was set to *LRCM.Client.Migrations.Configuration*, instead of *LRCM.Server.Migrations.Configuration* and that's most probably why I still have a ghost pending state.
**That's my first mystery:** How is this possible? When enabling migration I specified parameters for the correct *ProjectName*, *ProjectStartUpName* and *ContextTypeName*. Even tried specifying the *Configuration* or *ConfigurationTypeName* parameters without any change.

Long story told short, I really tried everything I could imagine to resolve that: renaming configuration class names, changing namespaces (one for each context), setting MigrationNamespace to migration configuration, setting ***ContextKey*** manually to configuration etc.

At the end I thought (project's still in initial state) I just remove my databases for server and client again, remove all migration files and folder from server and project, put my context classes in each of their corresponding projects (client, server) and only enable migration for my server for now, to assure this one is working before I enable migration for the client project as well.

Running `Add-Migration` looked promising, but running `Update-Database` taught me someting else.
Now I receive *(I received it also during my tests shortly told above)* an error about a table already existing. The relevant table is the one for my CoreEntities (also used by client context), but my migration file does not contain such *CREATE* statement twice.
I suppose somehow migration tries to merge my client and my server context - **but why?**
There's no link between them, except that they *share some entities*.

Looking again at DB site, I can see all my tables created and inside __MigrationHistory table - surprise: **still the same ContextKey** value.

**This is my second mystery:** 
Why is the ContextKey still the first one ever used in solution? Is it cached somewhere?
And why is migration trying to add my table twice, although migration file has only one *CREATE* statement?

For some code examples (code feature here is not good for long code input) please see another thread I've opened yesterday, but doubt I'll not receive any answer there: [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11a4d4aa-8cdc-49fc-bbff-4a436f8e472a/codefirst-migration-with-wrong-contextkey?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

I'd really appreciate any help I can get to fix this.

Regards,
Tom

***Edit 1:***
Meanwhile I've had little success at least.
I removed everything related to migrations from server and client project.
Commented my DBSet for CoreEntity in my server context.
Enabled migration for server project.
Added successfully a migration file.
Updated DB successfully.
Reset all migration stuff and this time used context with CoreEntity.
Adding migration and updating DB was again successful.
Enabled migration for client project.
Added migration and updated database successfully.

Before I enabled migration for client project, I've had another look in DB and this time I've seen two entries inside *__MigrationHistory*. One with the old (wrong) ContextKey and one with the correct one.
Therefore I've deleted all my databases again and executed `Update-Database`. And this time there was only 1 correct entry.

But now I have my pending issue again. No matter how often I run `Update-Database`.

This lead me to some other conclusion I had to check:
If I remove the database file from my project folder, migration warns about missing database. But if I than add this file as new DB again it works.
The issue I see (I think I do) is that migration updates my database under my build's *AppData* folder, where it's used during debugging, but checks (for whatever reason) for the database inside my project's *AppData* folder where there is only a database file without any tables.

**And I was right and at least found the cause**:
When I execute Update-Database it connect to my database inside the build folder structure, but not the database in project folder structure.

**So my final question (which I also will change in title) is:**
Why is EF code based migration checking for migrations in projects DB file, but only writing to DB file in build's DB file? Looks almost like a bug?!

Answer (score 0):

At the end - it really seems to be a bug. I can reproduce this erroneous behaviour even in new projects and guess it's something in my environment that does not work properly with EF 6 code based migrations.

Therefore I've ended up writing a bug report, that you can follow [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2335).

If someone else should be able to reproduce that behaviour, please participate on the bug report to get this fixed or find a workaround quicker.